# SQL: Unpack STRUCT to columns

Tags: sql, duckdb

I have a jsonl file I've read into duckdb that looks like this:

```
('conversation_id', 'BIGINT', 'YES', None, None, None)
('text', 'VARCHAR', 'YES', None, None, None)
('meta', 'STRUCT(case_id VARCHAR, start_times DOUBLE[], stop_times DOUBLE[], speaker_type VARCHAR, side UBIGINT, "timestamp" DOUBLE)', 'YES', None, None, None)
('reply_to', 'VARCHAR', 'YES', None, None, None)
('speaker', 'VARCHAR', 'YES', None, None, None)
```

The elements of the `STRUCT` are arbitrary in any given jsonl file I'm importing, but they're identical in every row, so I'd like to unpack the `STRUCT`, create a column for each element, and then get rid of the `STRUCT`.

I've seen a number of answers that variously cover casting the `STRUCT` or unpacking it in specific domains like pyspark or bigquery, but I don't understand how to do it in vanilla SQL.

Comment: Does your `struct` has different number of elements in some rows or the structure is going to remain the same throughout ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the struct.* syntax for this, eg

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3} as a);
```

returns

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

For more information: https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/struct#struct